# Unhandled exception after installing rebuilt C# project

Tags: c#, .net, exception, service, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to build/rebuild an old C# project at work which needs to be modernised. It runs as a Windows service. I made a few changes to update it, but when I built it, it threw an exception on start up. I undid all my changes and made sure there were no changes detected by Git. It stills throws an exception immediately after being installed. I have an old install file built in 2016 which still installs perfectly. <s>I also apparently built this project in 2017, 2018, and 2019 without any problems that I remember.</s> I just found an old installer I built in 2017 and it also throws an exception just after installation.

Selecting Build or Rebuild on the `My_Service_Setup` project makes no difference.

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: My_Service, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  My_Service -> C:\project\My_Service\bin\Debug\My_Service.exe
------ Starting pre-build validation for project 'My_Service_Setup' ------ 
------ Pre-build validation for project 'My_Service_Setup' completed ------
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: My_Service_Setup, Configuration: Debug ------
Building file 'C:\project\My_Service_Setup\Debug\My_Service_Setup.msi'...
Packaging file 'AutomaticUpdater.dll'...
Packaging file 'client.wyc'...
Packaging file 'Newtonsoft.Json.dll'...
Packaging file 'My_Service.exe.config'...
Packaging file 'wyUpdate.exe'...
Packaging file 'My_Service.exe'...
========== Rebuild All: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

The IDE is Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. I'm not using the same computer as last time, but the previous computer was running Windows 10 as is this computer.

[image: An unhandled Microsoft .NET Framework exception]

I can't debug it because it starts with the System user (as it should), and when I switch to the Administrator user in order to debug it the exception no longer occurs. The installer that works also installs the service to run under System, so the new installer is installing it to run under the correct user.

I also can't debug it from Visual Studio because services must be installed as services and can't be started from the debugger.

[image: Windows Service Start Failure]

What could be different about my setup from the original developer's that's causing this exception to occur? Am I missing some dependency that Visual Studio is not telling me about? Could there be a version incompatibility in .NET versions? I just don't know what's causing this unhandled exception.

Comment: _"I can't debug it because it starts with the wrong user, and when I switch to the right user the exception no longer occurs."_ - doesn't that tell you something?

Comment: @Fildor Yes, it tells me that Admin has full rights, but System doesn't. That doesn't help me solve the problem though.

Comment: @Fildor I just double-checked. The one that works without an exception and the one that throws an exception are running under the same user. It's exactly the same code, it's just been built at different times on different computers. So, no, the user appears to be a red herring.

Comment: Ok, that's really odd. Can you pinpoint any changes between the two versions?

Comment: @Fildor Unfortunately not. I had a crazy idea that it could be line endings, as VS2015 changes the line endings to CRLF on save, while they're stored in Git as LF. My working directory is completely clean. However, replacing the new `.exe` with the old one and restarting the service after installation fixes the issue. There are five files installed, one is a text config file, the others are binary and don't change except for my `.exe`. I can control if the exception is thrown without changing the config file just by manually replacing the `.exe` file.

Comment: @Fildor The line causing it was `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();` I've only just started reading up about that, and it seems it's _supposed_ to immediately throw an unhandled exception in order to bring up the Visual Studio interface. I also had an issue with the "Release" version of the code building, so I was always using "Debug". That was due to the project being set up by the original developer with a relative path to a required library. I changed it to an absolute path, built a "Release" version, and voilà! no more unhandled exception on start up!

Comment: Great catch! This shall be helpful ...

Answer (score 1):

This is a comedy/tragedy of (compiler) errors/exceptions. Visual Studio 2015 selected the "Debug" configuration when opened, and changing it to the "Release" configuration wouldn't successfully build the project. It is apparently expected behaviour for a debug build to throw an unhandled exception as soon as it starts. The line of code that does that is inside the compiler directive:

```
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
#if DEBUG
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
#endif
```

Commenting out that line stopped the unhandled exception on starting up the service, but was obviously the wrong way to solve the problem. I then looked at what the error in "Release" was. It was looking for a library file with a relative path instead of an absolute path. Since I had installed the project in a different directory from the original developer, it couldn't find that file, but strangely only for the "Release" configuration. The "Debug" configuration was able to find it and include it.

So, fixing the relative path and changing the configuration from "Debug" to "Release" fixed the problem!